# Baking Normals in blender

Tags: node-editor, normals, baking

[image]
When I try to bake normals using the settings in the image the normal bakes with weird colors and the object is unwrapped no doubles or inverted normals, can someone tell me what am doing wrong,thanks.

Comment: what does your object look like rendered with that displacement? Also plugging a vector output into a value input like displacement is not likely to produce good results. Before you even start baking you need to check that what you are actually trying to bake looks sensible.

Comment: Thanks seems I was oblivious about that but is there anyway better way to bake normals in blender